# hadoop shell command pretty slow

Tags: shell, hadoop, dns

I installed single-node hadoop cluster in my mac laptop. And today the hadoop shell become pretty slow. And it is pretty fast when I disable my wifi, but it is very slow when I enable my wifi. I don't know what's wrong with my wifi. I tried clean the dns cache, but doesn't work for me. Does anyone know what's wrong here ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem that was caused by network paths in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and System Integrity Protection disabled.

So if 
       csrutil status
reports disabled try to enable it (reboot in recovery mode, terminal, csrutil enable, reboot)